# Why is name resolution slow on my Mac

Tags: linux, networking, macos, virtualbox, dns

I have a Linux web server running in VirtualBox and after upgrading to Sierra I found that my sites on the web server are extremely slow to load.  It takes minutes.  I thought it had to do with something about the VirtualBox guest installation so I set up my sites in a Docker container but I'm seeing the same thing.

On a whim I turned off all networking and suddenly my sites load instantly.  This leads me to believe there's some kind of domain name resolution problem but I'm not sure where to look.

My development domains are in /etc/hosts which looks something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 firstdomain.dev
127.0.0.1 seconddomain.dev
```

When I `ping firstdomain.dev` I get this:

```
PING firstdomain.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
```

When I `host firstdomain.dev` I get this:

```
firstdomain.dev has address 127.0.53.53
firstdomain.dev mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.dev.
```

I don't understand why the OS isn't looking at /etc/hosts first and going from there.  What else can I look at or do to resolve this?

Edit: I have tried changing the .dev to .local but I still see the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was actually mod_authz_host in the VM.  It was trying to do a reverse lookup on the dummy domains and sometimes timing out, sometimes not.  Since I have no need for mod_authz_host I could safely remove it.  It is curious how the upgrade to Sierra caused this though.